# "Response object has no attribute 'body'"

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

I am using the following code which is mimicking an XHR request on a webpage to update the contents of a table object when a different tab button is selected on screen:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed/?field=1&isAscending=false&orderBy=Rating&playerId=-1&stageId=9155&teamId=32"'

params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fixtures = response.body
#fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
print fixtures
```

This is throwing up the error in the title of the post. I'm guessing I need to add the parameter 'body' somehow in the `requests.get()` statement, but I'm not sure how exactly. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

The attribute you're looking for is `content`

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://google.com')
>>> response.content
'<!doctype html><html itemscope=""...
```

Effectively, your code would look like this:

```
import requests

url = 'http://www.whoscored.com/stageplayerstatfeed/?field=1&isAscending=false&orderBy=Rating&playerId=-1&stageId=9155&teamId=32"'

params = {'d': date.strftime('%Y%m'), 'isAggregate': 'false'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)

fixtures = response.content
#fixtures = literal_eval(response.content)
print fixtures
```

Comment: ...hmm i was originally using response.content but that is not returning what i would expect to see, so i have tried to use response.body as i am familiar with that from scrapy. i was expecting the response to look more like a dictionary, as this is the data structure that underpins the table I am trying to parse.

Comment: @user3045351 the response comes in raw text, you can then parse it using the `json` library, given that the content in the response is json format, and you will have a dictionary.

Comment: when i run the above code i get an error saying the page does not exist, but if you enable xhr logging in the chrome developer console, that is the url for the xhr request submitted when you move between different tabs of a table on the webpage i am looking at...

Comment: @user3045351 alright, you have to parse the HTML to get the information you need. You can use `beautifulsoup` for that or `scrapy` as you mentioned, but that would be a different question.

Comment: the issue at the minute is that it is saying the page does not exist, but i will ask another question anyway...

Comment: @user3045351 change the url that doesnt exist to to the url you mentioned in the comment, I answered the question you posted here.